# Creating plugins for Onenote

Tags: onenote

I've been looking some at the Onenote API and it seems to me it's mainly to retrieve and post full pages (correct me if I'm wrong). What I wanted to do was to extend the functionality inside Onenote so I can pull data into my Onenote document while working in it. It could be something like making REST calls to a dictionary API or picture database API or similar. Is that possible to do in the Onenote API...or by using any other connectivity tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to extend the OneNote client à la [Onetastic](http://omeratay.com/onetastic/) then the only method is the [OneNote COM API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff925947%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

It exposes the full page object model and will allow you to interact with the OneNote client from your own Win32 application, which could easily connect to the resources you mentioned.

Comment: I was hoping for a more generic API that could be used on all platforms but I guess I have to settle with the COM API. Thanks for your reply...

Comment: Sorry :( What you can do is [vote for client APIs for OneNote on UserVoice](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-apis/suggestions/7048554-provide-client-apis-to-allow-offline-editing-witho). We use it to help prioritise our backlog and make sure we're building what users want.